# send UIImage to HTTP server Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, http, uiimage, nsurlsession

I send an image to a server HTTP with this code:

```
-(NSDictionary*)sendImage:(UIImage*)image withDescription:(NSString*)description andTarget:(NSString*)target andTargetId:(int)targetId {
__block NSDictionary *result = nil;
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", PREFIX_URL_REQUEST, SEND_IMAGE]]];
[request setHTTPMethod:REQUEST_TYPE_POST];
NSString *boundary = [[NSString alloc] init];
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];
NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"%@.%d\"rn", target, targetId] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Type: application/%@.png\r\n\r\n", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_%d", target, targetId]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[request setHTTPBody:body];
dispatch_semaphore_t sem = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
    NSLog(@"%@", result.description);
    dispatch_semaphore_signal(sem);
}];
[dataTask resume];
dispatch_semaphore_wait(sem, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
return result;
```

}

this is the server code:

```
 session_start();
if ( isset($_SESSION['username']) ) {
    $params = explode(".", basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]));
    $target = array_values($params)[0];
    $id = array_values($params)[1];
    if ( ($target == "profile") || ($target == "question" && $_SESSION["waitingImagesQuestion"] > 0) || ($target == "answer" && $_SESSION["waitingImagesAnswer"] > 0) ) {
        $imageDirectory = "images/".round(microtime(true)*1000).".png";
        if ( move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $imageDirectory) ) {
            switch ( $target ) {
                case "profile":
                    print JsonBuilder::putRecordProfileImage($imageDirectory);
                    return;
                case "answer":
                    $_SESSION["waitingImagesAnswer"] --;
                    print JsonBuilder::putRecordAnswerImage($imageDirectory, $id);
                    return;
                case "question":
                    $_SESSION["waitingImagesQuestion"] --;
                    print JsonBuilder::putRecordQuestionImage($imageDirectory, $id);
                    return;
            }
        } 
    }
} 
print JsonBuilder::getStringError();
```

works, but only when I call the client method so (`[UIImage imageNamed:@"aaa.png"]`):

```
[sender sendImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"aaa.png"] withDescription:@"" andTarget:@"profile" andTargetId:1];
```

if I call the method with an UIImage (for example a photo taken from the camera roll), so:

```
-(void)sendImage:(UIImage*)image {
    return [sender sendImage:image withDescription:@"" andTarget:@"profile" andTargetId:1];
}
```

doesn't work!
Why?

Thanks

Comment: the question is quite abstract. additional info is required. does Xcode debug console produce any output? Does the server error log produce any output? First of all you need to understand whether the http request is performed at all or not.

Comment: the code works, but only if I give to the method (to send the image) an image so: [UIImage imageNamed:@"aaa.png"] , when I give to the method an UIImage retrieved from camera roll doesn't work! @heximal

Comment: are you sure image is not nil at that moment?

Comment: yes! 
I've already checked! @heximal

Comment: maybe your server has some limitations on uploaded file size?

Comment: no, it is on my local machine without size limit!

Comment: UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) returns valid NSData object?

Comment: the NSData is not nil! @heximal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

now it works:

```
-(NSDictionary*)sendImage:(UIImage*)image withDescription:(NSString*)description andTarget:(NSString*)target andTargetId:(int)targetId {
if ( image != nil ) {
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.33f);
    __block NSDictionary *result = nil;
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", PREFIX_URL_REQUEST, SEND_IMAGE]]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:REQUEST_TYPE_POST];
    NSString *boundary = @"0xKhTmLbOuNdArY";
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];
    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"%@.%d\"rn", target, targetId] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Type: application/%@.png\r\n\r\n", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_%d", target, targetId]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [request setHTTPBody:body];
    dispatch_semaphore_t sem = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
    NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(sem);
    }];
    [dataTask resume];
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(sem, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
    return result;
}
return nil;
}
```